# How can I get FacetFilter work properly?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, nest

I'm trying to calculate some stats from elasticsearch with a short time period but, eventhough I specified the interval, I'm still getting results from the whole data set.

This is my code

```
var minDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var fromDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-11-27T11:00:00.000Z").AddTicks(-minDate.Ticks).AddHours(-2);
var toDate = DateTime.Parse("2014-11-27T11:15:00.000Z").AddTicks(-minDate.Ticks).AddHours(-2);

var results = client.Search<Dalsp>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(100)
    .FacetTermsStats(fts => fts
        .FacetFilter(fdesc => fdesc
            .Range(range =>
                range.Greater(fromDate.Ticks / 10000).Lower(toDate.Ticks / 10000)
            )
        )
        .KeyField(t => t.sp_name)
        .ValueField(t => t.total_time)
    )
);
```

What can be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after using strings for timestamp, instead of long.

```
 var results = client.Search<Dalsp>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Size(100)
        .Query(q =>
            q.Range(range => range.OnField("@timestamp").LowerOrEquals(endDateStr).GreaterOrEquals(startDateStr))
        )
        .FacetTermsStats(fts => fts
            .KeyField(t => t.sp_name)
            .ValueField(t => t.total_time)
        )
    );
```